# css media print using docraptor: How to flow header logo on every page and fix footer on the first page of pdf.

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to make a online form, which has header(with the logo of the company) and footer( with three different addresses). And in the body there are so many things. I need to flow the header logo in every page of the form but I need to fix my footer only on the first page not in every page.

For the header logo i am using 
@page { @top {content: flow(page_header); }} .

but when i use the same thing for the footer it is not working. Can anybody help me about this?

Note: I am using docraptor for converting the html into pdf.

Comment: I answered the question given you meant "static flows aren't working". Perhaps you meant you can't use the same element in the footer and header?

Answer (score 0):

Developer at DocRaptor here. You can do this using some simple CSS. Here is a full demonstrative example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
     h1 { flow: static(page_header); }
     h2 { flow: static(first_page_footer); }
     @page {
         @top { content: flow(page_header); }
     }
     @page:first {
         @bottom { content: flow(first_page_footer); }
     }
     hr { page-break-after: always; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Header Content</h1>
    <h2>Footer Content</h2>
    <p>Page 1 content.</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Page 2 content.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps! Email DR Support if you run into any different questions or want to say hi. :)

Comment: When I try out the above code on https://docraptor.com/try_it_out it renders perfectly. But when I render in on our project using the python api, the footer is not rendered